# What light pollution levels are required to see the Milky Way?

Tags: astronomy, light-pollution

I live in a Class-5 night sky on the [Bortle Scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bortle_scale), and you cannot see the Milky Way with your naked eye here. I was wondering what Class night sky I would have to be in to see the Milky Way's gas and dust clouds with my naked eye?

Comment: I think you are going to have to define what you mean by "*see the Milk Way*", because technically if you can see any stars at all you are seeing the Milk Way.

Comment: More suitable for [astronomy.se]

Comment: According to one UK map, the village where I live is right on the border of the bands labelled "2-4" and "4-8" and I can certainly see parts of the Milky Way on a clear night - unless I look straight at one of the nearby street lamps, of course. So assuming the map as correct, class 4 should be good enough. But that is a very poor view compared with a really dark sky (e.g. from the islands of the west coast of Scotland).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's more suitable for [Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @stafusa & other close voters: According to old meta consensus, [astronomy is on-topic at our site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1197/50583). If you think astronomy questions should not be on-topic now that [astronomy.SE] is a successful site on its own, please start a meta discussion about it instead of voting to close questions that are currently clearly on-topic. Our tagline is *"Physics Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for active researchers, academics and students of physics **and astronomy**"*, after all.

Comment: @ACuriousMind You're right. Here's [question on Meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13227/75633).

Comment: What's the problem with the Wikipedia description of each division that specifically include the visibility of the Milky Way? That would seem a minimal level of research before asking this question.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Wikipedia article on Bortle scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bortle_scale), at class 5 light pollution

> the Milky Way is very weak or invisible near the horizon, and looks washed out overhead

The brightest pollution level where the Milky is visible is described as class 6, bright suburban sky:

> the Milky Way is only visible near the zenith.

At higher level, 7, suburban/urban transition,

> the Milky Way is nearly or totally invisible.